# Microsoft Translator Text API EN to FR case inconsistency

Tags: microsoft-translator, bing-translator-api

I am using the Microsoft Translator Text API to translate some content from English into French, with category set to 'travel'. One of my requests looks like this:

```
https://api.microsofttranslator.com/v2/http.svc/Translate?appid=Bearer <token>&from=en&to=fr&contentType=text/html&category=travel&text=TRAVEL FROM INBOUND TRANSATLANTIC SECTOR MUST COMMENCE NO EARLIER THAN <span class="notranslate" id="1">{{days}}</span> DAYS AFTER DEPARTURE OF THE OUTBOUND TRANSATLANTIC SECTOR OR - TRAVEL FROM INBOUND TRANSATLANTIC SECTOR MUST COMMENCE NO EARLIER THAN THE FIRST SAT AFTER DEPARTURE OF THE OUTBOUND TRANSATLANTIC SECTOR
```

So **EN string** is:

> TRAVEL FROM INBOUND TRANSATLANTIC SECTOR MUST COMMENCE NO EARLIER THAN `<span class="notranslate" id="1">{{days}}</span>` DAYS AFTER DEPARTURE OF THE OUTBOUND TRANSATLANTIC SECTOR OR - TRAVEL FROM INBOUND TRANSATLANTIC SECTOR MUST COMMENCE NO EARLIER THAN THE FIRST SAT AFTER DEPARTURE OF THE OUTBOUND TRANSATLANTIC SECTOR

And response **FR string** is:

> VOYAGE du secteur transatlantique entrant doit commencer pas avant que `<span class="notranslate" id="1">{{days}}</span>` jours après le départ du secteur transatlantique sortant ou - voyage du secteur transatlantique entrant doit commencer pas plus tôt que la première SAT après le départ de la SECTEUR TRANSATLANTIQUE SORTANT

Note that capitalization in translated string is inconsistent with the English string, only few words are capitalized.

Also, I am seeing a different behavior when there is no tag in the string:

**EN:**

> TRAVEL FROM INBOUND TRANSATLANTIC SECTOR MUST COMMENCE NO EARLIER THAN 4 DAYS AFTER DEPARTURE OF THE OUTBOUND TRANSATLANTIC SECTOR OR - TRAVEL FROM INBOUND TRANSATLANTIC SECTOR MUST COMMENCE NO EARLIER THAN THE FIRST SAT AFTER DEPARTURE OF THE OUTBOUND TRANSATLANTIC SECTOR

**FR:**

> VOYAGE DU SECTEUR TRANSATLANTIQUE ENTRANT DOIT COMMENCER PAS AVANT 4 JOURS APRÈS LE DÉPART DU SECTEUR TRANSATLANTIQUE SORTANT OU - VOYAGE DU SECTEUR TRANSATLANTIQUE ENTRANT DOIT COMMENCER PAS PLUS TÔT QUE LE PREMIER SAMEDI APRÈS LE DÉPART DE L’ÉTRANGER SECTEUR DE TRANSATLANTIQUE

And when the category is set to 'generalnn':

> Les voyages en provenance du secteur transatlantique entrant doivent commencer au plus `<span class="notranslate" id="1">{{days}}</span>` tôt les jours suivant le départ du secteur transatlantique sortant ou-les déplacements du secteur transatlantique entrant doivent commencer au plus tôt le premier samedi après le départ du Secteur transatlantique sortant

Is there a reason for these inconsistencies? And is there a way to respect the case when using category=travel and tags?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for pointing out these issues. We should have a fix soon for the issue of respecting the case and we are investigating the issue of the tag.